# Dynamically load google fonts after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-face, google-font-api

I would like to be able to have the user select which font they would like the page to be displayed in.  [Here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader) is the way that Google recommends you do it using JavaScript.

```
WebFontConfig = {
    google: {
        families: ['Tangerine', 'Cantarell']
    }
};

(function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
            '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
```

How can I modify this so that I can re-get fonts after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check out the WebFont.load command in this github repo:

https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

You can load whatever font you want dynamically:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script> 
  <script> 
        WebFont.load({
                    google: { 
                           families: ['Droid Sans', 'Droid Serif'] 
                     } 
         }); 
   </script>
```

Comment: Be sure to use a specific version in production. Else there will be no caching.

Comment: @sanmai: thats not true...there is caching on the latest version for up to 1 year. I think the issue is more that a buggy release will break your site.

Comment: @DD. just checked to see that you're right; currently for the [version 1 as above in the post](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js) Google gives `Expires` header for a year ahead; previously this wasn't the case

Answer (score 13):

Or if you don't want third party libs :

```js
function addStylesheetURL(url) {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
}

// Load Tangerine & Cantarell
addStylesheetURL('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cantarell&family=Tangerine&display=swap');
```

```css
    h1 {
      font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
    }
    p {
      font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dynamically load google fonts after page has loaded</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dynamically load google fonts after page has loaded</h1>
    <p>Some text.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Load font:

  const fontName = 'Roboto';
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${fontName}`;
  document.head.appendChild(link);

// Set font on body element with Javascript:

  document.body.style.fontFamily = fontName;
```